# Problem about supremum and upper bounds

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $ \mathbb{R} \supset E \neq \varnothing$. Let $u \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose

$1.$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $u - \frac{1}{n} $ is not an upper bound of $E$.

$2.$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $u+ \frac{1}{n} $ is an upper bound of $E$

Then $u = \sup E $

#### Attempt:

By property $2$, we see that $E$ is bounded above by $u + \frac{1}{n}$. In particular, $\sup E $ exists, call it $\alpha$. We claim $\alpha = u$. Choose $\epsilon > 0 $ so that $ \epsilon > \frac{1}{n} $. This we can do by the Archimidean property. Next, notice that for every $n$, there is some $x \in E$ such that

$$ u - \epsilon < u - \frac{1}{n} < x $$

This follows by property $1$. Hence, $u = \sup E $

Is this a correct solution ? thanks

Comment: I think you mean to say, choose $\epsilon > 0$, then by the Archimedean property there exists $n$ such that $\frac 1n < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property 2) tells us that $\alpha:=\sup E$ exists with $\alpha\leq u+\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Consequently $\alpha\leq u$

Property 1) tell us that $u-\frac{1}{n}<x_n\leq\alpha$ for some $x_n\in E$ for each $n\in\mathbb N$. Consequently $\alpha\geq u$.